# Error using nested_form gem with empty association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nested-forms

In my rails app, I have two models, a `ClientPage` and a `ContentSection`, where `ClientPage has_many :content_sections`. I'm using the `nested_form` gem to both models to be edited with the same form. This works fine as long as the `ClientPage` has at least one `ContentSection`, but if there are no associated `ClientSections`, the using `nested_form`'s `link_to_add` method throws the following `NoMethodError`:

```
undefined method `values_at' for nil:NilClass
```

The form is structured as follows:

```
<%= nested_form_for page, form_options do |f| %>
  # ClientPage fields

  # ClientSections

  <%= f.link_to_add "Add new section", :content_sections %>
<% end %>
```

As long as there is at least one `ClientSection` associated with the page, this works fine. As soon as there isn't, the error is thrown. Removing the `link_to_add` also stops the error from being thrown. (There's actually a second nested model under `ContentSection`, and the same issue arises if there are no associated models.)

Not sure what I'm fairly obvious thing I'm missing, but any pointers or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about building a blank content section if none exists? From within controller: `@page.content_sections.build`

Comment: That's something I'd looked at, but it would mean making a bunch of extra changes to deal with the dummy objects (given I don't necessarily want to create one if one doesn't exist). I'll take that approach if need be, but I was looking for a more straight forward solution.

Comment: To be clear, that *is* the most straight forward solution, and suggested solution in the official guides. You're not creating new records, you're creating a blank instance. See here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#generating-a-controller

Comment: The section of the guides you linked to is talking about a different situation. If the `content_sections` association is empty, I do not want a form to add one, rather the `content_sections` section of the form should be empty. Again, this works fine, up until I use `nested_form`'s `link_to_add` method -- in this situation, that method causes an exception to be thrown, and I'm looking for a way to prevent that from happening without creating a blank instance, if possible.

Comment: In that case, I suggest you post an issue on github for `nested_form`. I have no idea about `link_to_add`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally worked this out -- the error was due to the fact that I was using the gem in a slightly non-standard way. Within the form, instead of rendering all of the content sections the standard way:

```
<%= f.fields_for :content_sections do |section_form| %>
  # section fields
<% end %>
```

I put it inside a loop, as I needed the index of each item (which is not stored within the model itself):

```
<% page.content_sections.each_with_index do |section, index| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :content_sections, section do |section_form| %>
    # section fields
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

The issue doing it this way is that the `fields_for` method does not get called if the association is empty, and as such the gem cannot build the blueprint for the object (which is used to add in the extra item when `link_to_add` is called).

The solution was to make sure `fields_for` got called even if the association was empty:

```
<% if page.content_sections.empty? %>
  <%= f.fields_for :content_sections do |section_form| %>
    # section fields
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```